# Export particles to xml

Tags: cycles-render-engine

how to export particles into xml ,l want to use standalone cycles render particles but l do not know how to do ,l think standalone cycles can render particles but the xml api interface can`t read particles data.what can l do ?

Comment: You can get the details of a particle system via Python. What format XML file are you trying to get? Can you provide an example of the final result?

Comment: sorry ,l don`t  know ,l read standalone cycles source code and found classes like particle and particlesystem,so l think standalone cycles can render particles ,but the xml api not provide method that read particle data,

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the particle coordinates using Python. I don't know what format XML you require but the following python code will extract the locations from the first particle system on the object named 'Cube' in the current scene and generate a fragment of XML defining each particle :

```
import bpy

object = bpy.context.scene.objects['Cube']
particles = object.particle_systems[0].particles

bpy.ops.text.new()

for p in particles:
    bpy.data.texts[-1].write("<particle x='"+str(p.location[0])+"' y='"+str(p.location[1])+"' z='"+str(p.location[2])+"'/>\n")
```

Simply open a Text Editor window, click 'New' to create a new text block and paste the above code. Amend the 'object = ...' line to change 'Cube' to the object owning the particle system and click 'Run Script'. This will generate a new text block (viewable in the Text Editor window) containing something like the following :

```
<particle x='-1.0000001192092896' y='-0.590164840221405' z='-0.06581293791532516'/>
<particle x='0.44954031705856323' y='0.9999999403953552' z='-0.2284814417362213'/>
<particle x='-0.7184286713600159' y='-0.7630156874656677' z='-1.0'/>
<particle x='0.20344652235507965' y='0.9787259697914124' z='-1.0'/>
<particle x='-0.9999999403953552' y='0.39420998096466064' z='0.5528056025505066'/>
<particle x='0.9186654686927795' y='-0.5270229578018188' z='1.0000001192092896'/>
<particle x='-0.21842864155769348' y='-0.7690218091011047' z='-1.0'/>
<particle x='0.34407132863998413' y='-0.6609137654304504' z='-1.0'/>
<particle x='1.000000238418579' y='0.7620397210121155' z='0.39064347743988037'/>
<particle x='-0.31608468294143677' y='1.0000001192092896' z='-0.07232522964477539'/>
<particle x='1.0' y='-0.04655367508530617' z='-0.9907378554344177'/>
<particle x='0.06282128393650055' y='-0.8771299719810486' z='-1.0'/>
<particle x='-0.3629598319530487' y='-0.36061328649520874' z='-0.9999999403953552'/>
<particle x='1.000000238418579' y='0.5745397210121155' z='0.3185715079307556'/>
<particle x='-0.384637713432312' y='-0.23795989155769348' z='1.0'/>
<particle x='0.16828972101211548' y='-1.0000001192092896' z='0.44469761848449707'/>
<particle x='0.9999998211860657' y='-0.12467917054891586' z='0.9131660461425781'/>
<particle x='0.19794464111328125' y='-0.7613976001739502' z='1.0'/>
....
```

Change the 'write' statement to change the format of the generated XML to whatever you require (currently it outputs each particle as a  node with attributes of 'x', 'y', 'z').

[Code for Blender 2.82a](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/171034/91071)