# I need to export a list of particle coordinates

Tags: python, scripting, particles

This code was built for Blender 2.78, but I trying build the code in 2.8.

Blender doesn't show any errors, just opens a new empty text file.

I'm using the code from [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96126/export-particles-to-xml):

```
import bpy

object = bpy.context.scene.objects["Plane"]
particles = object.particle_systems[0].particles

bpy.ops.text.new()

for p in particles:
     bpy.data.texts[-1].write("<particle x='"+str(p.location[0])+"' y='"+str(p.location[1])+"'z='"+str(p.location[2])+"'/>\n")
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Of Blender 2.78 to Blender 2.82 there were several changes.

Now the code that yes work:

```
import bpy

depg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
object= bpy.context.scene.objects['Plane']

particles = object.evaluated_get(depg).particle_systems[0].particles

bpy.ops.text.new()

for p in particles:
    bpy.data.texts[-1].write("<particle x='"+str(p.location[0])+"' y='"+str(p.location[1])+"'z='"+str(p.location[2])+"'/>\n")
```

I get to this code after find these links:

[Particles python access is broken in 2.8](https://developer.blender.org/T58792)

[Manipulating particles in python](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/manipulating-particles-in-python/7552/18)